# C++: goto and user input not working together

Tags: c++, string, authentication, if-statement, user-input

I am working on C++, and using a basic authentication method using if statements, so what I have here, is when the the input is not the desired combination, it will say Access denied and ask the user if they want to try again or quit. I tried doing this using the goto variable, but it hasn't been working. Help please? (Full code: https://pastebin.com/49LdGgJX)

```
    else {
    cout << "Access denied..." << " Try again? (Y/N) >" << flush;
    string ask;
    cin >> ask;
    if(ask == "N" || "n"){
      cout << "Shutting down..." << endl;
      goto end;
    }
    else if(ask == "Y" || "y"){
      goto restart;
    }

    else {
      cout << "Invalid option." << endl;
      goto restart;
    }
  }

  end:
  return 0;
```

Comment: the use of goto is a bad habit try to replace it with a while loop

Comment: The shown code in the question fails to meet the requirements of a [mcve], as explained in the [help]. All questions on stackoverflow.com must include all relevant information in the question itself. Links to external web sites that can stop working at any time are not acceptable.

Comment: "X is A or B" in English is "X = A or X = B" when translated into logic. You have "X = A, or B is kind-of true".

Comment: What means "it hasn't been working"? Does it crash? Does it not compile? If the latter, the error message should contain an information why.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I&#39;d upvoted you and then I started to wonder why `goto` is a bad idea here. `goto restart` actually pretty readable, at least more than `continue`.

Comment: @NO_NAME It isn't crashing, it has been ending the program, using the `if(ask == "N || "n")` statement, no matter the user input.

Comment: @Ron why does it evaluate to `true` though? Do you have a recommendation of code that would fix it? Or would I have to rewrite my whole code around a `while` statement?

Comment: @Yes. molbdnilo's comment is the answer.

Comment: You should be aware that the condition (ask == "Y" || "y") will always evalutes to true, because you're first checking if ask == "Y", and if this part is not true than "y" will be evaluted (not ask =="y"). So the result will be always true because "y" will be evaluaed as true.

Comment: I would suggest you look up the definition of spagetti code;  There's a very good reason why the basic language isn't used very much now.

Comment: @Yes. When you use `goto`, you've reduced the number of experienced programmers that want to help you by a large percentage.  No one is going to waste time looking at spaghetti (or potential) spaghetti code.  Also, one of the bad ways of using `goto` is when you're branching *up* to a label.  In other words, if you need to scroll up to see where you're branching to, that is a tell-tale sign spaghetti code is coming or has already established itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible break-ups of that code structure into more procedural way (wouldn't dare to call this "object oriented").
You can use similar way to break up menu handling code into separate functions for each option, etc.

If this would be multi-user app, then you may want to store instead of simple true/false full credentials of the user authenticated, like having a structure containing `name, code` (password probably can be thrown away after authentication to not keep it in memory long, if you don't need it later).

```
// returns true if user wants to exit
// sets authenticated to true when the Drew user is detected
bool AuthenticateUser(bool & authenticated) {
  cout << "Enter your username >" << flush;
  ...
  if (name == "Drew" && ...) {
    authenticated = true;
    cout << "Access granted. Welcome, " << name << "." << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to Database of Drew" << endl;
    return false;
  }
  cout << "Access denied..." << " Try again? (Y/N) >" << flush;
  ...
  return (ask == "N" || ask == "n");  // N = wants to exit
}

// returns true if user wants to exit
bool ProceedWithMenu() {
  cout << "1.\tAdd new record." << endl;
  cout << "2.\tDelete record." << endl;
  ...
  if (1 == value) {
    ...
  }
  if (5 == value) {
    cout << "Application quitting... " << endl;
  }
  return (5 == value);
}

void mainLoop {
  bool authenticated = false;
  bool exitApp = false;

  do {
    if (!authenticated) {
      exitApp = AuthenticateUser(authenticated);
    } else {
      exitApp = ProceedWithMenu();
    }
    // repeat authentication / menu until user decides to quit app
  } while (!exitApp);
}
```

This example is still quite crude and oversimplified, just trying to illustrate power of `do {} while`, `return`, and similar. Often also `continue` and `break` can be of great help to control the flow of code execution, without any `goto` and labels.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements are wrong as:

```
if(ask == "N" || "n")
```

always evaluates to `true` because the `"n"` operand always evaluates to `true` and you are using a logical `OR` operator. The string literal of `"n"` decays to `const char*` pointer whose value is not `0` thus evaluating to `true`. What you want is:

```
if(ask == "N" || ask == "n")
```

and:

```
else if(ask == "Y" || ask == "y")
```

That being said don't use `goto`.